# How to make faster vecnorm to a 3D array

Tags: performance, multidimensional-array, octave, bsxfun

I have a program to calculate the evolution of a system of N particles with equal mass attracted by gravity. When I execute a profile of the program, I get the first 7 functions that take the longest are for the calculation of the acceleration of the system (91% of the time execution), which is okay because it is the hardest part of the problem. However, I want to know if there is a better way to do it.

My acceleration program is as follows:

```
function [A] = aceleracion(R)
  Rij=R-permute(R,[2,1,3]);
  A = sum(((vecnorm(Rij,2,3) + 0.05).^-3).*Rij , 2);
endfunction
```

Here, R is the variable where the data of the position is saved and it has 3 dimensions: rows separate particles, columns separate timesteps, and the third dimension is for xyz coordinates.

Comment: You don’t need `bsxfun` any more since Octave 3.6.0. You can just directly add or element-wise multiply two arrays. See https://docs.octave.org/v9.1.0/Broadcasting.html

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, thank you. The code is much cleaner without the bsxfun

Comment: you're clearly using Octave code and have tagged octave. you should remove mention of matlab in the title unless you have specific need for Matlab related feedback.

Comment: by itself vecnorm is performing a fairly simple calculation `sum(abs(A).^P)^(1/P).  since sum can also be applied just along one dimension, and it uses compiled code, coding that line directly may help by avoiding the overhead of the extra m-file call.  Additionally you can also use the profiler to see where your code is spending the most time

Comment: I will try that, seems reasonable. I launched a profile and the most consuming time are sqrt, binary + and .^-3